# How to prove to CodeContracts that IEnumerable<T>.Single() never returns null?

Tags: c#, code-contracts

I have the following code snippet:

```
    public static string returnString()
    {
        string[] stringList = { "a" };

        if (stringList.Count() != 1)
        {
            throw new Exception("Multiple values in list");
        }

        var returnValue = stringList.Single();

        Contract.Assert(returnValue != null, "returnValue is null");

        return returnValue;
    }
```

CodeContract says:

> CodeContracts: assert unproven. Are you making some assumption on Single that the static checker is unaware of?

In my understanding, `Single()` never returns null - it returns either the exactly only value of the IEnumerable or it throws an exception. How can I proof this to the code analyzer?

Comment: `Single` _can_ return null if the collection contains just a null value.

Comment: Looks like the static analyser isn't good enough to know that `stringList` is hardcoded to only contain `"a"`.  Arguably a bug in Code Contracts.

Comment: It could also be argued that, while considering the edge case above, both validations can be combined to a single call to SingleOrDefault() and an assert on null.

Comment: Also FWIW, ReSharper doesn't flag a "possible NRE" on `returnValue`, even if `stringList` is hardcoded to a single entry of `null`.

Comment: For complex inferences that are beyond the scope of what the static analyzer can see (such as depending on the content of the constant-initialized array), consider using `Assume` rather than `Assert`.  It clarifies that you're making an assumption based on your understanding of the code, even if the static analyzer can't prove it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> In my understanding, `Single()` never returns null

Not true -

```
string[] a = new string[] {null};

bool check = (a.Single() == null);  // true
```

> It returns either the exactly only value of the `IEnumerable` or it throws an exception.

*That* is correct - so if the collection contains just a single null value then `Single` will return null.

Comment: That's really clever! I never considered that as possible result of `Single()`.

Comment: I think people assume that ALL Linq methods never return `null` since the methods that return a _collection_ will return an empty collection instead of `null`.  The methods that return a _value_ (`First()`, `Single()`, etc.) can certainly return null.